# How to open a vim terminal in the full area of the vim buffer?

Tags: vim, terminal

I really like the built-in `:terminal` in recent vim versions. I have one pain point though: sometimes (often?), I would like the terminal to take the full vim window size. However, usually, using `:terminal` only uses a partial split on half the vim window size, even if I start from an empty buffer. From an empty buffer, using `ctrl-w o` maximizes.

Any way to open at once into a "full size split" that takes the full vim buffer, instead of needing the extra `ctrl-w o` step?

Answer (score 4):

You can do `:tab terminal` to open a terminal window in a new tab page.

You can do `:terminal ++curwin` to open a terminal in the current window.